# Border Radius covers up the edges of my picture, but why?

Tags: html, css

This has actually never happened to me before, and no matter how many padding I give to the picture, the edges are still covered up a little bit. Here is a picture (as you can see, it is not happening for every icon - the third one has a normal round background):

[image: https://ibb.co/1G7DfW4]

My CSS (you probably don't even to see as much of it as I posted here):

```css
.tweet_messagebox_iconbox {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(65, 65, 65);
}

.iconrow {
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 70px;
}

.singleicon {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: rgb(17, 17, 32);
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tweet_messagebox_iconbox">
                <div class="iconrow">
                    <img class="singleicon" src="blabla.svg">
                    ...
                    ...
```

Comment: Please provide something that we can use to reproduce your issue. The [mre] you have posted seems to be missing the actual behavior you described in your question.

Comment: Please use the real url for `<img>`.

Comment: from the look of the screenshot, why do you even need a border radius?   if your image is larger than the circle, the bits of the icon that overflow will be hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `border-radius` on `<img>` is the reason why they are clipped at the corners. Apply `border-radius` to the element that contains the `<img>`, also if you want a perfect circle it should be `border-radius: 50%`. The other changes are just added for the sake of completeness. The changes to HTML are optional.

*Significant changes are commented with  `/* ✢ */`.*

```css
.bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly; /* ✢ */
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(65, 65, 65);
}

.orb {
  display: inline-flex;     /* ✢ */
  justify-content: center;  /* ✢ */
  align-items: center;      /* ✢ */
  border-radius: 50%;       /* ✢ */
  background-color: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.4);
}

.ico {
  display: inline-block; /* ✢ */
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 9px           /* ✢ */
}
```

```html
<nav class="bar">
  <a href="#" class="orb">
    <img class="ico" src="https://i.ibb.co/bBNQZW2/stop-1470.png">
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="orb">
    <img class="ico" src="https://i.ibb.co/Hx860HY/arrow-all-376.png">
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="orb">
    <img class="ico" src="https://i.ibb.co/JjNnNsb/javascript-155.png">
  </a>
</nav>
```